# How to auto fix checkstyle warnings of FinalLocalVariable and FinalParameters by Intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea, final, checkstyle

Code Style has rules:
FinalLocalVariable
FinalParameters

It will give warning like:
Parameter XXX should be final.

Some people just don't add final while they are writing the code. In case your team has some practice to add that. How can we easier add them up?

Answer (score 3):

Find it in Setting -> Editor -> Inspections.
Search for keyword "final". In "Code style issues", check "Local variable or parameter can be final" and make sure "Report local variables" and "Report method parameters" are checked.

Then run Analyze -> Inspect Code. Make sure select the profile just created in "Inspection profile".

Then you can auto fix them in "Inspection Results" panel.
[image]

[image]